# Does $\overline{ B_r(p) }=B_r[p]$ imply that (X,d) is connected?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let's consider a metric space with it's typical base. Suppose that $\overline{ B_r(p) }=B_r[p]$. It implies that the metric is continuous, if we consider space (X,d) with X as domain and $([0,+\infty),|x-y|)$ with $[0,+\infty)$ as codomain.But what about [connectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space)? If you know counterexample write it , if it is possible that the statement is truth , prove it.

Ad 1.

(X,d) is such a space that if d is Euclidean distance then (X,d) is connected. 
Without Ad 1. question is trivial.

Ad 2.

$B_r[p] = \{x \in X: d(p,x) \leqslant r\}$

$B_r(p) = \{x \in X: d(p,x) < r\}$

Comment: From $\overline{B_r(p)}=B_r(p)$ we have that every open set is closed, so $X$ is connected if and only if $X$ has one element.

Comment: @Math1000 $B_r[p]$ means the *closed* ball.

Comment: @Darius $\mathbb R\setminus\{ 0\}$ with the usual metric satisfies your assumption. Also, the metric is *always* continuous, without any additional assumption.

Comment: @Etienne Read Ad 1. It was written before your response.

Comment: @Darius But Ad 1 doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Etienne You don't understand. It's extra assumption but not an assertion.  So question is : Does $\overline{ B_r(p) }=B_r[p]$ and Ad. 1 imply that (X,d) is connected?

Comment: @Darius You're right: I don't understand. You assume that $(X,d)$ is connected, and you want to know if it is connected?

Comment: @Etienne "...(X,d) is such a space that if d is Euclidean distance then (X,d) is connected..." , note that I've written "if", which implies that not only that case is considered, so you can assume that the space (X,Ecd) where Ecd is abbreviation for Euclidean distance is connected and d is such a metric that $\overline{ B_r(p) }=B_r[p]$ . Question here: Is the space (X,d) connected?

Comment: @Daris In this way, this makes sense...; and the closure is with respect to which metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X:=\mathbb R$. Choose a bijection $\phi:X\to\mathbb R\setminus\{ 0\}$, and define a metric on $X$ by 
$$d(x,y):=\vert \phi(y)-\phi(x)\vert\, . $$

Then $(X,d)$ is isometric to $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ endowed with the usual metric. So it is not connected and yet $\overline{B_r(p)}=B_r[p]$ for all $p,r$; and of course Ad 1 is satisfied.

Comment: So $\phi(x)$ is continuous between metric , topological spaces $(X,d)$ and $(\mathbb{R}-\{0\},Ecd)$ what implies disconnectedness. You've disconnected space $\mathbb{R}$ , +1 anyway.